# Logistic Regression using dummy variables in MATLAB

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, matlab, logit

I have a model where categorical (mutually exclusive) variables predict bankruptcy. Chi-square is significant. How can I code a logistic regression model in `MATLAB` that proves that some of these variables explain the bankruptcies better.

There are 4 variables: which implies 3 dummy variables.

```
X = [  0 0 0
      0 1 0 
      0 0 0 
      0 0 1 
      0 0 1 
      1 0 0  
      1 0 0 ......... ] ;
Y = [1 0 0 1 1 0 0 .....]; % 1 means bankruptcy
```

I think I should use `glmfit` (from http://matlabdatamining.blogspot.com/2009/03/logistic-regression.html) but I wasn't sure if using dummy indicators would require any additional interpretation/inputs. I use latest version and have Statistics and Optimization Toolbox.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MATLAB code. Please take this kind of question to Stack Overflow or a MATLAB forum.

Comment: @NickCox, it does belong on SO, but we can migrate it for the OP.

Comment: People on SO often object to questions without (serious) code, as when the OP just is asking generally about some program, command or function, but I am happy to let this question have its chance.

Comment: Isn't there a statistical question lurking here about the appropriate way to code categorical variables for making [some kind of as-yet unexplained] comparisons?  If there is, Maddy, then could you please edit your question to make this emphasis more apparent and to help us understand better what you are looking for?

Comment: @whuber @gung I'm hoping to learn 3 things here: 1. Is there intercept term the slope for the remaining variable that wasn't used in the N-1 dummies?  2. The slopes are the odds for event happening.  Eg, exp(Beta1) will give me the odds for bankruptcies happening when X1 is true. exp(Beta2) will give me the odds for bankruptcies happening when X2 is true...... 3. A coding example where entire logistic regression can be interpreted.  `glmfit` gives me stdev, betas, stderrors, p etc for training and test sets.  How do I decide my model's accuracy.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `glmfit` and create dummy variables yourself. If you include a constant term you would want to omit one of the dummy variables.

However, as of late 2013 there is a `fitglm` function that can handle categorical predictors for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'd interpret the intercept as the remaining dummy variable?  More specifically, exp(intercept) would give me the odds of bankruptcy happening when that dummy variable was TRUE?

Comment: That sounds right. The intercept would then represent the value of the omitted level. Coefficients of other levels would be added to the intercept to get the fit for those other levels.